# Can't pass objects returned by Observable as input component Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a small component where I have only one input

#### Ts component Code

```
 @Input() variables;

      ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.variables);
    }
```

#### Where I use my component TS

```
envVars$: Observable<{
            names: String[],
            values: {}
          }>;
```

#### Where I use my component HTML

```
 <app-code  [variables]="(envVars$ | async)?.values | json"></app-code>
```

In the console log I HAVE NULL though my object is full

Comment: can you please post the whole ts code of the component?

Comment: I don't know why the async pipe returns NULL

Comment: It's working when I switch to         <app-code>{{ (envVars$ | async)?.values | json }}</app-code>
This is really weird!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: did you try to remove the json pipe?

Comment: My only guess is that the expression evaluation works different that input binding... Does `<app-code variables="{{ (envVars$ | async)?.values | json }}"></app-code>` work?

Comment: @EduardoVargas the problem comes of the sync pipe .

Comment: @Osman Cea yes I tried but it returned an error of synthax

Comment: the log says null because you're logging ON INIT before the object has been asynchronously defined. The async pipe is working exactly as intended. if you need the object to be defined on init then you need to change your structure a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the log says null because you're logging ON INIT before the object has been asynchronously defined. The async pipe is working exactly as intended. if you need the object to be defined on init then you need to change your structure a little.

do this instead to ensure the observable is populated prior to component instantiation:

```
<app-code *ngIf="envVars$ | async as enVars" [variables]="envVars.values | json"></app-code>
```

the ngIf here tells angular to not instantiate the component until envVars$ emits a value.

Comment: I'll try your solution as soon as possible.

Comment: you've got something messed up somewhere along the line, check your code